Missing function "__libc_init_array" in libc.a GCC 14.2.0 arm-none-eabi
I built the GNU GCC C\C++ ToolChain for ARM-none-eabi under Wiondows11 and MSYS2 using the most up-to-date components:
binutils-2.43
GCC-14.2.0 n
newlib-4.4.0
GDB-15.1

I have a problem compiling an ST example whose startup-file use the function __libc_init_array.
Compilation stop  with error "undefined reference to '__libc_init_array'"
This is because library \arm-none-eabi\lib\libc.a does not contains this function.
In the build log file there is this error:
checking for .preinit_array/.init_array/.fini_array support... yes
checking for symbol prefix... 
      1 [main] readelf (4544) child_copy: cygheap read copy failed, 0x800000000..0x80003E900, done 0, windows pid 4544, Win32 error 6
  50700 [main] readelf 796 C:\MSYS64\home\etica\GccAM0_142\arm-none-eabi\bin\readelf.exe: *** fatal error - couldn't create signal pipe, Win32 error 5

Building the ToolChain with the same build-script and same source items on an another similar PC (windows11 and MSYS2) everything works and \arm-none-eabi\lib\libc.a contains the function __libc_init_array.
Please, what can I investigate??
